# Asked a lot to a coworker. Should I apologize?

Tags: colleagues, email

So this is the situation:

I work on a product delivered by A, and I have a lot of questions on the product. I usually go to A's desk (far from mine) and ask, or sometimes by mail with a list of questions.

I did that for a few months, and today before going to A's desk, I asked by mail "Can I come to ask some questions?"

A answered: "No, I have things to do. Give a mail with your questions and I'll answer later".

Finally we met and we worked together on the subject.

I am wondering if I can do something "perfect" for the future. So what is the best behaviour for next question:

- Ask by mail if I can come by?
- Ask questions directly by mail (might be inefficient sometimes)?
- Go to A'sdesk directly (I think that one is bad...)
- Apologize for having gone to A's desk before and ask for A's prefered communication mean

Answer (score 10):

You asked,

> I am wondering if I can do something "perfect" for the future

The best thing to do is probably take a step back and confirm if "A" is the best official source you have.

If you are having enough trouble with your work that you need to constantly rely on asking someone else questions, you may want to check in with your boss and let them know. They may be able to either change your work assignments or give you direction on how to get the help you need, either from A or from another source.

Assuming you know that A is the person you're supposed to ask for help, then it sounds like your best recourse at this point is to simply **ask A what they prefer.** We can't really tell you what would be best for *them* but they probably can. So, maybe you can send them an email along the lines of,

> Hey, it seems like I need to rely on asking you about this system on a regular basis. How would you prefer that we work together in the future? Would you like me to just send you a list of questions, or maybe set up a regular check-in meeting? Or do you have another idea that would work better for you?

This way, you can give them the freedom to describe what works best for them, and then you can just follow that guideline - and you won't have to worry about what they prefer in the future.

As a minor footnote, in the title to your question, you asked,

> Should I apologize?

Apologies are always nice when appropriate, but what really shows that you care will be *taking action* to carry out your requests in the best way in the future.

Comment: Another way to show you are taking action is a culturally appropriate "thank you" gift. Just something small (food seems to work well in most places) with a note that essentially says "I know I was a bother but I appreciate the help you've given"

Answer (score 3):

It's better to hear a single thank you than many sorrys.

Do not say sorry, say thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As I've been on the receiving end of this....

I'd really recommend you stop going by that person's desk unsolicited for these questions. I'd even go so far as to say.... Don't send a skype asking if you can call, or asking if you can stop by their desk on short notice. The polite thing would be to schedule a meeting with a reasonable notice period, or ask your questions via email.

The method of communication you choose implies a specific urgency. If you send an email, realistically, you might not get a response for a few hours or a day. If you ping someone on skype or call them, the common expectation is that you're going to get a response within a minute or two. If you stop at someone's desk, you're interrupting everything they're doing and (even if you didn't intend to) demanding that they address your thing before you'll walk away and leave them back to their work.

This can be really irritating to the other person if they've got stuff to do that's important, especially if the things you're bugging them about aren't....important to them. Especially the desk intrusions.... If you did this enough, I could see the potential for someone else to even make a complaint to their / your manager about the frequent unplanned interruptions and you might receive a bit of a note that you should plan these things more formally and exercise better judgement / consideration for others. 
That's not to say that you should just schedule dozens of meetings - people hate this too. If it's short, send an email; If you think you need 15-20+ minutes of someone's time to work through and plan something, schedule a meeting for it. Unless you have a really good, strong relationship with someone.... **Don't just stop at their desk and interrupt them.**

If you're not engaged in any formal project or specific joint work with this individual, you should probably think about just emailing them. This way, ***when they have time, they will get you a response and won't think much of it.*** This applies for things that you might feel the urge to schedule a meeting for out of your own convenience, that could really actually be handled in email as well. If you're taking up someone else's time on something that they technically wouldn't have to spend time on, I'd opt for the least intrusive method unless you have a strong need for it or support from a manager for a formal project.

If you expect you'll have to occupy a ***significant amount*** of this person's time, you should consider asking your manager to engage their manager to plan a time for you to work together as a formal project, as they then will have some relief from their other work rather than having the same deadlines and expectations regardless of who walks up to their desk and pesters them

As far as apologies.... I'm not sure. A simple email might be appreciated; I wouldn't recommend sending over skype as there's then an implication that you need a two-way conversation on the subject and the other person might have weird feelings about just ignoring it or whether they have to respond... Perhaps if your company has a formal recognition system like VIP per department, perhaps nominate them? Maybe leave a nominal gift at their desk with a card saying thanks for all the help?

If they're saying "No" when you ask to meet at their desk, I would imagine you've probably gone far enough to annoy the other person, but this happens and I wouldn't think too much of it, simply spending a bit more consideration on methods of communication in the future will probably improve things on its own

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say apologise - but always thank them for their help and, every now and then, go a little further to show your appreciation. (Something like "I appreciate you taking the time to help me with that").

It's natural that you will need time to learn the business, the product, the process etc. It's important however, that you aren't asking the same question multiple times. If you are not learning/growing from what they are telling/showing you, it will quickly become irritating to them. Start a document or wiki as a reference for yourself (and others who might come after).

As you are getting more comfortable with the role, instead of asking "how do I X" go with "I need to do X...am I right in thinking that the way to go about this is ...".  This shows you are learning and, if you have a good handle on things, might only require them to say "yes - that's exactly it".

The medium of communication you use depends on how urgently you need the answer. You have to do your job in a timely manner - sometimes that will mean walking to their desk to have a face to face conversation when they might not have a lot of time. You should be confident enough to push a little if they try to dismiss you if you need the answer there and then.

But as dwizum says - make sure they are the best person to ask these questions of.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something nice for the person?  That goes a long way.  Perhaps buy a gourmet coffee, or donuts or something.  While it is, probably, within their expectation to help you the could be jerky about it.  Doing something nice in recognition respects the value they bring to the workplace and it shows something about yourself as well.  Spending a small amount of your own money can go a long way.  As an example, if they were a tea drinker, buying them a box of tea would be a nice gift, and a negligible amount spent.

Along those lines, you could go to your boss and sing this person's praises.  Same thing for their boss.  If you received any recognition for a job well done, make sure you include this person.

Not only will you make this person feel good about a job well done, and let leadership know what a value they are to the company, but you yourself will be displaying good leadership.